# Arrange an expression based on functions' names

Tags: functions, sorting, expression

I have a problem of arranging an expression as shown in the following picture. The first expression `disorderF` is derived from other functions and equations, which is disordered. I want to get two results like (2) and (3). `sortedF1` (2) is a whole expression, but it appears in the order of `U1`, `U2`, and `U3`; `sortedF2` (3) is another form, it is formed from three sub-lists about `U1`, `U2` and `U3`.

Can you give the approach to obtain the results? Thank you.

**Note**:

The name `sortedF1` and `sortedF2` in expressions (2) and (3) are only for the convenience to express my problem, not variable symbols.

The codes have been presented in the end of the post.

**Picture**

[image]

**Codes**

```
disoderF = a*U3[x1, x2]*m*n + b*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]*q + c*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]*m + d* \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]*n + e*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + f*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U3\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + g*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + h*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2];  (*1*)
sortedF1 = b*q*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + d*n* \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + h*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + c*m*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + e*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + g*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + a*m*n*U3[x1, x2] + f*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U3\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2];  (*2*)
sortedF2 = {{b*q*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + d*n* \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + h*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U1\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"2", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]}, {c*m*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + e*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2] + g*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U2\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "1"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]}, {a*m*n*U3[x1, x2] + f*\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(U3\), TagBox[RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],Derivative],MultilineFunction->None]\)[x1, x2]}};   (*3*)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function that extracts any of `U1`, `U2` and `U3` when it appears as a head or as the argument of `Derivative` in the input expression:

```
ClearAll[functionNames]

functionNames = Cases[
  ((f : (U1 | U2 | U3)) | Derivative[__][f : (U1 | U2 | U3)]) @__ :> f];
```

***Examples:***

We can separate the terms in input expression using `MonomialList`, sort the resulting list using `functionNames` and then combine the sorted list using `Inactive[Plus]`:

```
sorted1 = Inactive[Plus] @@ SortBy[functionNames] @ MonomialList @ disoderF
```

[image]

To get the second result, use `GatherBy` to group monomials, sort each sublist by `functionNames` and then combine each sublist using `Inactive[Plus]`:

```
sorted2 = If[Length @ # == 1,First @ #,Inactive[Plus] @@ #] & /@  
  GatherBy[SortBy[functionNames] @ MonomialList @ disoderF, functionNames]
```

[image]

**Note:** A much simpler pattern is possible, if `U1`, `U2`, `U3` can appear anywhere (not necessarily as a function head or as the argument of `Derivative`) in the input expression:

```
ClearAll[functionNames2]

functionNames2 = Cases[ #, U1 | U2 | U3, All, Heads -> True] &;
```

For the example `disorderF`, replaceing `functionNames` with `functionNames2` in the examples above we get the same results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it can not give the right results like yours, click [the link](https://s4.ax1x.com/2022/01/13/7Mybuj.jpg) to see the result please.

Comment: @likehust, I had copy/pasted the wrong version of `functionName`. Please try the updated version.

Comment: Perfect solution, thank you very much. I would be very grateful if you could explain the magic of `functionName` or give me some tips about writing `functionName`. Thanks again.

Comment: @likehust, updated with a more general version.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see an easy way for "Sorted1" because MMA will at once, during output, reorder the expression.

However, "Sorted2" is easy. If we first change the expression into a list,  we may use "SortedBy"

```
SortedF2 = 
 SortBy[List @@ 
   disoderF, # /. { __ (U1[__] | Derivative[__][U1][__]) -> 
      1, __ (U2[__] | Derivative[__][U2][__]) -> 
      2, __ (U3[__] | Derivative[__][U3][__]) -> 3} &]
```

[image]